# Changing/moving/opening Directory

Tags: command-line, desktop-directories

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux command line operations.  I am using them as part of a bioinformatics project I am working on for my undergraduate degree.  I have a file of data that I want to access.  I have moved it on to my desktop and was trying to change directory to the desktop one.  I was not able to do so, says that it can't find it.
What I want to do is to be able to access the data in the files in the command line, then I can download programs in the shell and manipulate the data for my project. So how can I access the file (data) from the command line shell?
Any help is graciously accepted!!!

Comment: Where exactly did you store the file? If you don't know, `find -name "*FILENAME*"` shows you the path.

Comment: Instead of *" I was not able to do so, says that it can't find it. "* it would be more helpful to post the **actual** command you typed and the **verbatim** error message that resulted

Answer (score 2):

Well,

There's a lot of information you're requesting but I'll do what I can. The easiest way to get to your Desktop, from anywhere is to use `cd ~/Desktop`. This will move you to your Desktop folder and then from there you can access the data file. If it is a text file you can open, read, and edit it in the command line using a CLI text editor such as Nano, VI, or VIM.

An interesting tip that took me awhile to figure out is if you press `TAB` after starting to type either a command, file or folder it will auto-complete the name in most cases, but you may have to type more than one letter.

For instance if I wanted to move to the Desktop I could type `cd ~/Des` and then press `TAB` and it will autofill to `cd ~/Desktop`.

There is a lot more you can do with the Command Line it is VERY powerful.

One resource I recommend for getting started is to take the course on [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) (Yes it is spelled weird) over Learn the Command Line this will go over the basics and familiarize you with the basics of command line operation.

Comment: Thank you all for responding.   So I kind of generally know how to move around directories, but in the home directory (/home/username like davidhcefx said below) I should have been able to just cd ~/Desktop.  However it would say that directory did not exist.  The file is stored on my desktop, it is a folder actually.  I need to be able to access the fastq format files I have to run bioinformatics analysis, but I can't even find the folder even though it is on my desktop.  I will Codecademy resource as well as the CLI guide below.

Comment: This machine, is it a server?

Comment: Um I don't think so?  I'm just running this on my personal desktop.

Comment: And it tells you your Desktop doesn't exist?

Comment: Ya basically.  I accidentally did the mkdir command and made a desktop directory, but it is empty and not including anything when i do ls command.

Comment: If you run `cd ~/` and then run `ls` do you see multiple Desktops, or what is listed there?

Comment: it just shows the desktop directory that I made when doing the mkdir command, and when I enter that directory and do ls, it is empty

Comment: Are there other Directories in your Home folder?

Comment: the home folder only shows my username as a directory

Comment: And inside that?

Comment: the desktop directory that I made that is empty

Comment: So you see this file on your Desktop but not in the directory?

Comment: Exactly! Yes lol

Comment: If you drag and drop the file or folder into a terminal session it should give you the path to the file.

Comment: Yes I have done that, I know the path, but I can not get to it.  I try cd and the path and it is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic CLI guide on [How to Use the Linux Command Line: Basics of CLI](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-use-linux-command-line-basics-cli)

For beginners, the first command recommended is `ls`, which would list out the files and directories in the current directory. Use `ls -l` to list a more detailed info, and `ls -a` to list out hidden files or directories (names that starts with a dot '.').

To move from one place to another, use `cd [some/path/to/target]`, without the square brackets. When you opened up a shell (terminal), it's likely that your current directory is at */home/YourUserName*. You can check this out by `pwd` (print-working-directory). If there's a file at */FolderA/FolderB/File.txt*, and you're already under */FolderA*, you can simply use the **relative path** `cd FolderB` to go under FolderB instead of the **absolute path**. Use `cd ..` to move one step back in the directory.

To execute a file, type `./[FileName]`. You can only do this on files that have **execute permission**. Press `TAB` when typing file names or command names, and it will **auto-complete** the name for you. This is useful since you don't have to type all of the exact name, plus this also avoid typos. Other commands are: `mv /placeA/target /placeB/` for moving files or directories from one place to another; `cp fileA fileB` for coping a file or directory; `rm` for removing files; `mv nameA nameB` for renaming a file or directory (it's the same as the move command), etc. Google to find more Linux Commands.